# Blocking visitors by time zone?

Tags: timezone, block, country

I was searching for a solution to block visitors from a specific country, and saw that it is not that simple (requires an updated database of IPs, etc.).
So I was thinking... what if I recognize the timezone of the user, and block it if it's equal to the timezone of the country I'm interested in blocking.
I would like to ask for your opinion about this idea, and if you would recommend doing it, and what would be the easiest way of implementing it? PHP?

P.S.
There probably can be an issue with seasonal changes.

Thank you!

Comment: even if you could do that, instead of blocking one country, you would block also several others on the same timezone

Comment: Yes, it's okay - I don't mind blocking all the countries on the same timezone in order to block the specific one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  Apache module [mod_geoip2](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/) to do this.

> The mod_geoip2 module embeds GeoIP database lookups into the Apache
>   web server. It is only capable of looking up the IP of a client that
>   connects to the web server, as opposed to looking up arbitrary
>   addresses.